# Android studio: cannot find symbol variable toolbar

Tags: java, android-studio-2.3

I'm a newbie in android studio and I'm following the tutorial guide
[androidhive](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/06/android-getting-started-firebase-simple-login-registration-auth/). However I'm stucked at the LoginActivity.java part and the author doesnt feel like want to solve it as well. The thing is that when I compile the code,

> Error:(41, 54) error: cannot find symbol variable toolbar

showed up and highlight all the code with R.id, if I delete the toolbar code:

```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

the code can be compiled but then when you install and open it in the phone it will crash. I've read through a lot of thread and all they said is clean the project or rebuild the gradle, but it is not working.

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.testapps.basicsinter;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private Button btnSignup, btnLogin, btnReset;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }

        // set the view now
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        btnSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btnReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reset_password);

        //Get Firebase auth instance
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnReset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ResetPasswordActivity.class));
            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                //authenticate user
                auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // there was an error
                                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                                        inputPassword.setError(getString(R.string.minimum_password));
                                    } else {
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getString(R.string.auth_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.testapps.basicsinter.LoginActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/logo_w_h"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:hint="@string/hint_password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <!-- Login Button -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:text="@string/btn_login"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_reset_password"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_forgot_password"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />
        <!-- Link to Login Screen -->

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="@string/btn_link_to_register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testapps.basicsinter">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignupActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testapps.basicsinter"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Please upload correct gradle file

Comment: I don't see any control with the id toolbar

Comment: How can I add control to the id toolbar? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar) 
you should include Toolbar in your layout.

First make a toolbar layout.
`my_toolbar.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar"
      android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"  
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<!-- Layout for content is here. This can be a RelativeLayout  -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Then include it in your layout (in your case `activity_login.xml`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.testapps.basicsinter.LoginActivity">

<include
        layout="@layout/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<!--Rest of your layout content-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Then you can use `Toolbar`.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: Sorry but the code itself have problem since the author just simply copy paste the code to the page. Still a very detailed answer though :), thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that none of your UI elements in `activity_login.xml`, has the id `toolbar` that you are mentioning here:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Also, I believe that you repeated the manifest file, when in fact, you wanted to show the gradle file on the description of your question :).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, its edited now. How do I add  the id `toolbar`? Because i pretty much jus copy and paste the tutorial code.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbar element is missing in `activity_login.xml`. The codes for toolbar are

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

If any other errors occur, comment below.

Comment: How can I add it back in? Thank you.

Comment: Open `activity_login.xml` and add the toolbar element. Seeing the tutorial, the codes for the toolbar elements are given under `activity_main.xml`. See the edited answer for the code.

Comment: Sorry but the code itself have problem since the author just simply copy paste the code to the page. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the tutorial before and here is how I work around it. The gist is in the last step, but I recommend changing all the following code below.

First, under your manifest

```
    <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Second, remove the code, unless you need toolbar for compelling reasons, I don't see a point of including it in.

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Third, replace the coordinator layout with LinearLayout and add in the orientation to be vertical

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Lastly and the most important step, add the following to build.gradle (app). At my time, it was 24.0.0. The current version as of date is 26.1.0.
Please adjust accordingly to the appcompt version

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was adding the following to the imports.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Sometimes when I comment some code and auto format using command+option+l - the imports are removed automatically but when I remove the commenting problem arises.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Their issue was not finding the `R.id.toolbar` element, not the `Toolbar` class.